# How to flush socket pools and clear Dns cache in all browsers pragmatically

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, google-chrome, browser

After changing the **HOSTS** file >> I need to clear the dns cache and flush socket pools without restarting the browsers normally am doing this following [LINK](http://www.download3k.com/articles/How-to-Flush-or-Clear-Reset-Google-Chrome-s-DNS-Cache-and-Sockets-00853)

In windows 7 I flush from command line using  **ipconfig /flushdns**   and **nbtstat -R**  but still need to close the browsers
I am changing the host frequently  to check the update in Production Server and Local server
Is there any way to do it from code using c# or any executable tool??

Comment: You should have a look at PowerShell. See [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/powershell/windows/dnsserver/clear-dnsservercache).

Answer (score 1):

Invoke Windows Api `SetTcpEntry`

Or just use this [hosts switcher](https://github.com/tinycedar/lily/releases)