# How to programmatically clear internal Google Chrome DNS cache on Windows?

Tags: c++, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, dns

Is there a way to programmatically clear internal Google Chrome DNS cache. Note that I mean the inner cache of the browser, not the OS cache that can be cleared with `ipconfig /flushdns` Obviously `DnsFlushResolverCache` winapi in "dnsapi.dll" is not an option either, since it clears OS DNS cache. Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Theis question was asked and answered before see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48247949/1058222 about `SetTcpEntry`

Comment: If the questions are indeed duplicates, then please flag the question, rather than posting an answer. If the questions are related, but not duplicates, you should expand upon the answer (in your own words), instead of just linking to another answer.